# How to find the electric field due to a point charge in 3 dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, textbook-erratum

A point charge with charge $+q$ is situated at $(x,y,z)$. How do I find the electric field at $(p,q,r)$? $E=k\frac{q}{r^2}$, right? So why isn't the electric field, $E=k\frac{q}{(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2+(z-r)^2}$ ???

Question:
A charge $q=1\,\mu C$ is placed at a point (1m, 2m,4m). Find the electric field at point P (0m,-4m,3m).

I end up with $E$ = 2.38x10$^2$ N/C; the given answer is 1.46x10$^3$ N/C

Comment: Why do you think that's not the correct expression for the field? Also, this seems like a homework question. I'll tag it as such.

Comment: I came across a question, I'll update the post.

Comment: My answer is no where near to the actual answer. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there an other procedure to follow?

Comment: I get the same answer as you. I wonder if there's an error in the question.

Comment: That could be it... I'll check up with my teachers...

Comment: Which reference is the question from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your (correct) answer and the incorrect given answer is a factor of 6.16, which is the length of $(x,y,z)-(p,q,r)$ in meters.  Your textbook answer is the value of the potential at $(p,q,r)$, in volts.

Comment: Note though that the "answer" is given in the (correct) units of $N/C$. I would get another text book...

Comment: I don't know that I'd throw out the whole book — nobody's perfect, and nobody's editor is perfect either. It'd be polite to report the erratum to the author, though.

Comment: OK maybe I exaggerated. A note to the publisher might be more appropriate. Everybody helps a bit, the world becomes a better place. That's why we are here, right?